# Dictionary search in Vim

Tags: search, dictionary, vim

I have a dictionary defined in Vim. I need to do a search in a text file and match all ocurrences of the words in the dictionary.

For example I could do a search /[[:alpha:]] and match all letters in my file, I was thinking of something like /[[:dictionary:]] that matches all the words in the previously defined dictionary. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the matches once you've identified them? Do you need to bounce a cursor from match to match, or just visibly highlight them? If the latter, you could add syntax matchers programmatically with VimL, based on your dictionary file.

Comment: I'm counting words, i.e. taking the frequency of all words in a file. This I do by using "tip 1531" (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_frequency_statistics_for_a_file). I just can't figure out how to do it with specific words, that is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to count words from a dictionary, assuming the words consist only of ASCII letters, and the dictionary has exactly one word per line:

```
tr -cs A-Za-z '\n' <file.txt | fgrep -xof dictionary.txt | sort | uniq -c
```